# When x=0, y=25 and when x=150, y= 80. What is x when y = 60?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is primary school level algebra but for some reason I have forgotten how to think today.

I have an equation where at:

```
x = 0, y= 25
x = 150, y = 80
```

And I need to find out what x is when y = 60.

I figured if y = 25 when x = 0, then there must be an addition part to the equation, which must be 25.

So when x is 150, y must be 80 multiplied by a number, plus 25. So:

```
150x = 80y*a + 25y
a = 1.5625
```

So when y is 60:

```
bx = 60y*1.5625 + 25y
b = 118.75
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't be multiplying 25 by y. From the first equation, we know y=bx + 25 (assuming the equation is linear). Plug 80 in for y, 150 for x and solve for b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your function is linear:

Indeed, if $y = 25$ when $x = 0$, then there must be an addition part to the equation, which must be $25$. So we have $y = ax + 25$.

We also have that $y=90$ when $x=150$, so

$$90 = a \cdot 150 + 25$$

Solve for $a$:

$$a = \frac{90-25}{150} = \frac{13}{30}$$

Thus

$$\boxed{y = \frac{13}{30} x+25}$$